# read the file dynamically without giving static reference of the file

Tags: java, resources

I am currently working on a simple java project created in the eclipse IDE.
My project structure is as shown in the below picture. In the resources folder i have a file "sample.txt" which i want to read dynamically.

[image]

Below is the sample code i tried which is returning **null** value.

```
  InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("../../sample.txt");
```

Main objective is i want to read the file(sample.txt) but does not want to give hard-coded references for the file and when this project is run in any other system also my code should work. Any inputs would be helpful.

Comment: Your code will already work on any system provided you package the JAR file correctly. NB Resources are not files.

Comment: Please read my question..i am getting null value for the inputStream, it is not reading the file located in the path mentioned in that code i have shown above. @user207421

Comment: Please read my comment. The path is wrong, i.e. you didn't package the JAR file correctly. The correct path is `"/sample.txt"` or possibly `"/resources/sample.txt"`. Resources already have system-independent paths. You just have to get them right. NB There is no `File` or  `FileInputStream` here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`getResourceAsStream()` looks for files in classpath and there are no "directories" on the classpath so you can not give `"../../sample.txt"`.

Also `getClass()` method is not static and you can not directly run it from main method. You will get

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object

You can use `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(FilePath)` which will look for the file in your your classpath,
Try following code,

```
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("sample.txt");

InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
try {
    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @user3684675 added answer over there. Please up vote if it helped you.

Comment: @user207421 Updated the answer. Appreciate your valuable feedback.